# How to set cell as percentage in xls - phpoffice

Tags: php, phpoffice

Hey all I want to set the format of a cell in xls to percentage.
I am using phpoffice.
the value that I want is 0.04% as percentage.
the problem the origin $innervalue is 0.04% as string.
this is my code:

```
if($column == 'E') 
                        {
                            $innervalue = str_replace('%','',$innervalue); //remove the % sign for float
                            $innervalue = (float)$innervalue;              // set innervalue as float and not string
                            $sheet->setCellValueExplicit($cell, $innervalue, \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\DataType::TYPE_NUMERIC); //put the inner value as number
                            $sheet->getStyle($cell)->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('#.##%'); // format the cell for 0.04%
                        }
```

the problem is that the cell displayed 4.% instead of 0.04%.

if I remove the line

```
$sheet->getStyle($cell)->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('#.##%'); // format the cell for 0.04%
```

in the xls displayed 0.04 as number, but I need it to display in the xls 0.04% as number

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution:

Need to get the format from this link
https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/blob/master/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Style/NumberFormat.php

```
 if($column == 'E') 
                       {
                         
                             $sheet->setCellValue($cell, $innervalue); //put the inner value as number
                             $sheet->getStyle($cell)->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\NumberFormat::FORMAT_PERCENTAGE_00);
                         }
```